# Determine Barcode type by String representation

Tags: c#, barcode

Is there any way to determine Linear Barcode type by it's string representation? I mean, I have a recognized barcode "063211012927" and what to know what type is that? (In that case it's UPC-A.) Implementation in C# would be great, but algorithm also appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about GS1 standards. I don't know anything failproof for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because that string is simply the decoded text, it says nothing of the barcode symbology which was used to store it.

You could make some assumptions based on size and content (i.e., max data lengths and the fact that there are only numbers), but you will be wrong quite often and it's not what I would call a "solution".